# Error when calling method

Tags: java, processing

In my FloodFill class, I defined a `resolution` method that I want to call in `setup` or `draw`. But when I add `resolution(String[] args);` to call it, I have an error saying that I miss a right parenthesis.

Here is the whole code:

```
static int[][] matrix={
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1},
    {1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,1},
    {1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,3,2,1},
    {1,2,3,4,1,1,1,4,3,2,1},
    {1,2,3,4,1,1,1,4,3,2,1},
    {1,2,3,4,1,1,1,4,3,2,1},
    {1,2,3,4,4,4,4,4,3,2,1},
    {1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,1},
    {1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1},
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
  };

void setup() {
  size(1000, 600);
  noCursor();
  noStroke();
  fill(0);

  // periodic updates
  if (!callback) {
    frameRate(60); //<>//
    loop();
  } else noLoop(); // or callback updates 
  //int[][] array = new int[10][10];
  //System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
  tuioClient  = new TuioProcessing(this);
  System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(grid));

resolution(String[] args) ;

}


void draw() {

  // This part detects the fiducial markers 
  float obj_size = object_size*scale_factor; 
  float cur_size = cursor_size*scale_factor; 

  ArrayList<TuioObject> tuioObjectList = tuioClient.getTuioObjectList();
  for (int i=0; i<tuioObjectList.size (); i++) {
    TuioObject tobj= tuioObjectList.get(i);
    stroke(0);
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    pushMatrix();
    translate(tobj.getScreenX(width), tobj.getScreenY(height));
    rotate(tobj.getAngle());
    rect(-80, -40, 80, 40);
    popMatrix();
    fill(255);
    x = round(10*tobj.getX ());
    y = round(10*tobj.getY ());
    iD = tobj.getSymbolID();
    int taille = fiducialsList.length;
    for (int o = 0; o<taille; o++) {
      if (iD == o) { 
        myType = fiducialsList [o];
      }
    } 
    //System.out.println(myType);
    activList.add(new Fiducial (x, y, iD, myType));
    fiducialCoordinates ();
    grid [x][y] = 1 ;

    circuitState ();
    for (int p = 0; p < 10; p++) {
      for (int r = 0; r < 10; r++) {
        System.out.print(grid[p][r] + " ");
      }
      System.out.print("\n");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
    // activList.removeAll(activList);
  }
  for (int[] row : grid)
    Arrays.fill(row, 0);
}

void fiducialCoordinates () {
  System.out.println(activList);
}


public static class FloodFill {

  public static void resolution(String[] args) {
 // Do stuff
  }
public static void solve(int[][] matrix, int x, int y, int fillValue) {
// Do stuff
}
```

When I call other methods (for example `fiducialCoordinates ();`) it works fine. Is there another way to call this method since it's defined in a particular class ?

This is java used in Processing.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call a method, don't specify the type of the parameters:

```
resolution(args);
```

should work (except that `args` are nowhere defined - you need to pass those to the `setup()` method from the `main()` method).

Furthermore, `resolution` is defined in a seperate class, so you have to call it like this:

```
FloodFill.resolution(args);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. With this I get the error "the function resolution(String[]) does not exist" even though it is defined in FloodFill

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `String[]` when calling.

`FloodFill.resolution(args) ;`

should be enough

Comment: Thanks for answering. With this  I get the error "the function resolution(String[]) does not exist" even though it is defined in FloodFill

Comment: FloodFill.resolution(args); is how to call it